# Wordpress - post status - publish vs draft

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I have implemented login/register possibility on wordpress page. All registered users are registered as "subscribers". Users have possibility to add and edit posts ("custom post type") from the page where I implemented form for creating and editing posts. 
When users input all required fields (on that page) for post they have possibility to save-and-publish or save-and-unpublish (so they can continue with editing that post and they can publish it when they are ready).

So, I found myself in this problem.

- When user click on save-and-publish button, everything works fine, I change post_status to "publish" and its public and everything works fine.
- If user click on save-and-unpublish I change post_status to draft! (and here I have problem)
  Is there possiblity to show this draft (only to user who created it). Something like preview?

Comment: Let me get this straight, you made a separate form that piggy backs wordpress's post feature?

Comment: could you not set it as private to that user?

Comment: Im not sure i understand you? I implemented separate form for inserting posts in db. (Regular form like any other, used for alowing logged in users to inserting posts in db)

Comment: @Elliott arent "private" alows view only to editors and admins? Sorry im not familiar with this, that was main reason because i asked this quesiton :)

Comment: @Elliott tnx...simple answers are always the best.. I just tried to set post_status to private and it works perfect, only user who create posts can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to get into lengthy modification of WordPress custom capabilities... It sounds like you need something like this..

This is a filter I found somewhere that removes posts from the edit-posts page for non-admins/authors.  I came across it when I had to limit functionality for certain users.

```
/*
Show posts only owned by current user
*/
function posts_for_current_author($query) {
    global $pagenow;

    if( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || !$query->is_admin )
        return $query;

    if( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        global $user_ID;
        $query->set('author', $user_ID );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');
```

I can't remember where I found this, if I locate the source I'll come back and edit.

Comment: I already solved it with "private" post status, instead of draft. I appreciate your help.. tnx